# Mobile Tools for Java 1.1.0 plug-in to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-me

i tried to add `Mobile Tools for Java 1.1.0` plug-in in eclipse juno but it shows the below error

```
Error
Thu Dec 06 12:20:33 IST 2012
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/updates/1.1.0/stable.
```

is there any-other way to add this plug-in ?

Answer (score 0):

There is already version 1.1.2 available at http://download.eclipse.org/mtj/updates/1.1.2/stable/
But `MTJ` is known for not working with `Juno`. Please, try it with `Indigo`.

Comment: Thanks @Telmo but any suggestion for juno